# Sandbox Virtual Machine for an Application (C++ vs. C#)

Tags: c#, c++, performance, virtual-machine, sandbox

I'd like to write [a sandbox virtual machine for executing a compiled program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056340/sandbox-virtual-machine-for-an-application-concept). How do you think: which of these two languages would be better to use if we consider performance? Or maybe you suggest another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance of your VM will be much more affected by how you implement it rather in what language. If you implement it the same way in c# and c++ the performance will be comparable.

The thing that speaks in favor of c++ is that you can execute parts of the native code from your sandboxed application directly. It is possible to do the same in c#, but that requires some translation and emitting corresponding byte code with `Reflection.Emit`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in C#, I guess, because there are several things that would require assembler, not talking about unmanaged code itself. So C++ with some assembler would be the only option.